# html_session, read_html, readLines, GET, getURL all freeze

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rcurl, httr

For months I have been able to read this page, but starting Wednesday, it freezes.

```
myURL <- "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fb"
webpage <- readLines(myURL)
```

I've tried:

1. read_html  (rvest)
2. html_session (rvest) also reset user agent - no change.
3. readLines  This used to be all I needed.  Now it freezes like every other approach.
4. GET (httr)
5. getURL (RCurl)
6. Tried all of these both through R studio on a Windows box and directly in R on an Ubuntu server.  Freezes everywhere.
7. Poked around with the Chrome Developer Tools on the network tab to try to understand why this loads easily in browser and not at all in R. I didn't see any smoking gun, but I'm not an expert.

If anyone can figure out how to get the page without it freezing, that is all the help I need to get unstuck.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code that you used?

Comment: Edited to show the readLines() example.  This is the simplest case, but the RCurl, httr, and rvest approaches also freeze.

Comment: There is insufficient information to debug this. You could have finally run afoul of their [robots policy](https://www.naasdaq.com/robots.txt) resulting in an IP ban. You may be behind a transparent proxy or firewall with recently changed rulesets. You may have a default user-agent that the site doesn't like to respond to. Your systems may have had hosts file changes or be pwnd. Proper debugging protocols are required to help further.

Comment: Yes, it could be a bot thing, but I have tried several IPs so if they have ID'd me, it isn't by IP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which parts of the webpage you want to collect, but I had success getting some of the vital info with this code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/fb"
read_html(url) -> foo
html_nodes(foo, css = "b") %>% html_text()
```

Are you able to run the code above? Does it give you what you need? Depending on which pieces of data you need from the website, you might need to use a tool like SelectorGadget to find the css values that you need.

I hope that this helps. If it doesn't, please elaborate.

Comment: That freezes on the "read_html(url) -> foo" line.  I tried this both on my windows box with Rstudio, and in an R shell on a linux server.  Same result.

Comment: what do you mean when you use the word "freeze"? The above works for me on a MacBook pro.